# Facebook tracking AND Google tracking Script

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, google-analytics, tracking

I have allready Google tracking conversion. Now I need Facebook pixel tracking also.

My Google Head Script looks like this:

```
<script>
 (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
 (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
 m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
 })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

 ga('create', 'XX-XXXXXXXX-X' 'auto');
 ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

My JavaScript Call for Google looks like this:

```
if (typeof ga !== 'undefined')
 {
   ga('send', 'event', 'Blub', 'blub');
 }
```

Now I need to add Facebook tracking and I got this Script from Facebook:

```
<script>(function() {
  var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
  if (!_fbq.loaded) {
  var fbds = document.createElement('script');
  fbds.async = true;
  fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
  _fbq.loaded = true;
 }
})();
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
window._fbq.push(['track', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX', {'value':'0.00','currency’:'XXX'}]);
</script>
```

How can I integreat the Facebook code without to distrub the Google Code? 
And is there a problem if I use both?

BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it without any issues.

```
<script>
/* Facebook tracking */
(function() {
  var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
  if (!_fbq.loaded) {
  var fbds = document.createElement('script');
  fbds.async = true;
  fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
  _fbq.loaded = true;
 }
})();

/* Google Analytics tracking */
 (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
 (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
 m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
 })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

 ga('create', 'XX-XXXXXXXX-X' 'auto');
 ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

For the event:

```
if (typeof ga !== 'undefined')
 {
   ga('send', 'event', 'Blub', 'blub');
 }
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
window._fbq.push(['track', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX', {'value':'0.00','currency’:'XXX'}]);
```

Comment: may i know.. what is the purpose of this code(facebook tracking).. i have a doubt about this, I need to implement in my shopify store.. can you please explain me? thanks

Comment: @saina - it's only if you are running facebook ads. More info: https://www.facebook.com/help/435189689870514/